# When and where to use nHibernate in a project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

Having created a functional test project using nHibernate with all the typical trimmings I've got a very good handle on how I can leverage nHibernate, well at least as much as I can so far.  However, I'm wondering how other developers handle scenarios where the application needs to retreive data from the backend database that may run complex queries with joins / grouping for say reporting purposes or other tasks that fall outside of the OO paradigm.

Should I take the pure route of utilising nHibernate to execute these queries and fill the appropriate Repository objects regardless of its performance OR should I simply go straight the database passing a dataset back through the business layer?

Ultimately I'm comfortable using nHibernate for interacting with simple and complex business objects but there are situations where I feel that simply delving into the database makes more sense, and working as the only .NET developer atm I'm very interested in how other devs have handled this situation...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be pragmatic about it.

Many "complex" queries can be easily expressed in HQL, but if SQL is a better fit for some, by all means use it.

The reporting scenarios in particular are usually better suited for reporting tools that go directly against the DB.

Comment: +1: Use nhibernate to make your life easy for the typical oo stuff...for your reporting needs either make use of its raw sql facilities or just use sqlclient directly. Nhibernate doesn't have to solve *every* problem in your typical enterprise app.

Comment: Thanks, completely figures into my thinking - however, after much research and reading its hard to get out of that 'purist' approach to development...

Answer (score 2):

**NHibernate offers much more than simple querying.** The answer depends on what you need. Some examples:

- Automatic mapping of data to classes;
- Automatic change tracking;
- Database independence;
- Multiple choices in querying the database (currently 7) with support for easy refactoring;
- Integrated caching capabilities;
- Much much more.

If any of these properties fit your project, then yes, choose NHibernate.

Comment: Pieter, given that you're experienced with nHibernate how would you handle a situation where you need to a complex chunk of data for reporting purposes.  Would you utilise nHibernate or go directly to the database to retreive this data where it is (possibly) easier to monitor the performance and scalibility of the call?

Comment: I don't believe you have to worry about performance. You have a lot of freedom in describing your queries, and performance should not be a problem. Concerning monitoring: eventually, your queries become normal SQL and your current reporting tools still work. Currently I am working on an end-to-end platform based on NHibernate and I can say that for me the only option is to have the reporting tool go through NHibernate. That's where your domain model is :).

Comment: OK, so for clarification, I've got a scenario where I'll need aggregate data in large chunks, say 100k rows.  In this circumstance you would load all these objects into memory and perform agrregate functions on that data within the BL (or even presentation layer) or utilise a custom object that loads the aggregated data from the database?

Sorry, I'm just trying to get a feel for things and I appreciate your feedback :)

Comment: 100k rows is a lot yes. Hmmmm. With these kind of numbers I personally would try to split them up in smaller chunks and process them separately. However, I have the feeling that dedicated tools probably fit better with this scale and I would probably go looking for something that fits this scale better. NHibernate is good at domain and business logic. Just raw data processing, well, there are better tools for that.

Answer (score 1):

If your reports have relatively simple joins/grouping, then Nhivernate will be ok.

If you have complex queries for reporting purposes, Nhibernate may not be the best solution. I would recommend SSRS (Sql Server Reporting Service). It will be easier for grouping and other advanced functinality such as exporting to word/excel.

It really depends on the complexity of your reports.